# Is the map $f(x)=x+\cfrac{1}{4}\sin^2(\pi x)$ uniquely ergodic?

Tags: analysis, dynamical-systems, uniform-convergence, ergodic-theory

> Let $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be the continuous map $$f(x)=x+\cfrac{1}{4}\sin^2(\pi x)$$ Is $f$ *uniquely ergodic*?

**Note**: If $X$ is a compact metric space and $f : X \rightarrow X$ a continuous map, then $f$ is said to be *uniquely ergodic* if

$$\cfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\phi\circ f^k$$

converges to a **constant** uniformly for every continuous function $\phi$.

---

I suppose one way to approach this problem is to show that the time averages converge to the value at $0$, but I'm not sure how to make it work here.

Any hints? Thank you.

Comment: The statement is true if we identify the endpoints of the interval to get the unit circle; see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4383186/169085.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$.  So if you take $\phi$ to be the identity then $n^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \phi(f^k(0)) = 0$ and $n^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \phi(f^k(1)) = 1$ for all $n$.  Therefore this expression is not converging uniformly to a constant as $n \to \infty$.